# How do I fix this 'No file or directory' error

Tags: python, arrays, image, iterator

I am trying to iterate through a directory and print out the data from each image in the folder, but I keep getting an error saying an image file in the folder doesn't exist, despite it being in there.

```
import os 
import PIL
from PIL import Image
from numpy import asarray

directory = r'C:\Users\9devi\OneDrive\Desktop\Dog or Car\Dogs'
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    print(filename) 
    image = Image.open(filename)
    data = asarray(image)
    print(data)
```

Comment: Check if your working directory is correct using `import os` `os.getcwd()`. You also can concatenate the directory and filename string: `directory + "\" + filename`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the directory name with the filename.

ie

```
directory = r'C:\Users\9devi\OneDrive\Desktop\Dog or Car\Dogs'
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    print(filename) 
    file_path = os.path.join(directory, filename)
    image = Image.open(file_path)
    data = asarray(image)
    print(data)
```